# How to use the latest version of react-router-dom in the chrome extension with the vite as package manager

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, vite

I am planning to use the react-router-dom in my React app chrome extension but getting the dependency error:

here is the code of the content file:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./src/App";
import "./src/index.css";
import {
  createMemoryRouter,
  RouterProvider,
  Route,
  Link,
} from "react-router-dom";

const router = createMemoryRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <Link to="about">About Us</Link>
      </div>
    ),
  },
  {
    path: "about",
    element: <div>About</div>,
  },
]);

let isReactAppAdded = false;  

function removeExistingReactApp() {
  const existingElements = document.querySelectorAll('#tubechat-ai');

  existingElements.forEach((element) => {
    try {
      element.remove();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error in removal ", error.message);
    }
  });
}

function addReactApp() {

  const sideBox_inner = document.getElementById("secondary-inner");

  const videoDurationElements = document.getElementsByClassName('ytp-time-duration');

  console.log("videoBootom",videoDurationElements[0].textContent)
  
  if (sideBox_inner && !isReactAppAdded) { 

    removeExistingReactApp()

    const app = document.createElement("div");
    app.id = "tubechat-ai";
    sideBox_inner.insertBefore(app, sideBox_inner.firstChild);
    ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("tubechat-ai")!).render(
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
);
document.querySelector('#tubechat-ai')

    isReactAppAdded = true

  } else {
    console.log("Not all required elements are present.");
  }
}

document.addEventListener("yt-navigate-finish", addReactApp);

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", addReactApp);
```

I am using **vite** as package manager

I tried to use the **memoryRouter** also but still getting the issue.

I even tried to use history package but still getting the issue.

The main issue I am getting is this:
[Terminal Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0Ou3.png)

The vite config file is this:

```
import { resolve } from 'path'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  define: {
    'process.env': {}
  },
  build: {
    outDir: resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    lib: {
      formats: ['iife'],
      entry: [
        resolve(__dirname, './content.tsx'),
      ],
      name: 'Conntent-Script Vite Configuration'
    },
    
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        entryFileNames: '[name].js',
        extend: true,
      }
    }
  }
})
```

I suppose the **main error lies with the use of vite with react-router-dom** as much as I found in the internet

Comment: What is the issue? You mention you have some error, what is the error? We can't really help if we don't know what the problem is. Please [edit] to clarify what you need specific help with. Ensure your post has a complete [mcve] of all the relevant code you are working with.

Comment: Have update it please have a look now.

Comment: Does this [post](/q/72795666/8690857), or [post](/q/75925195/8690857), or [post](/q/74620427/8690857) help answer your question?

Comment: No still getting the error tried to put  `  _global: ({})` but it didn't work. My motive is to use the react-router-dom -A third party package to get build by vite so definitely its a config file error. I even tried to put dependency externally but still the same issue

Comment: Lot of context missing, such as how you setup your project.
Multiple issues in your code:
* The official CSS module script import statements have the syntax `import name from 'path/file.css' assert { type: 'css' }`.
* Why do you use the MemoryRouter instead of the recommended BrowserRouter for browsers? Why do you import "Route" when unused?
* The expression after `ReactDOM.createRoot(…).render(…);` inside `addReactApp()`  has no effect (and is falsly indented).
* stack trace mentions Rollup?
* your path uses `about` instead of `/about`

Comment: PS: Sorry, your CSS module import syntax seems to be right.

Comment: I have used `ReactDOM.createRoot(…).render(…)` to put my chrome extension in the Youtube DOM I had to use it I suppose.
I have used `MemoryRouter` because I don;t want to use the browser history for the extension. but it isn't working actually.